# Programmable clock generator IC and reference circuit

Tags: clock, clock-speed

I need a clock source for some data converters (DAC, ADC), and I would like the clock frequency to be as configurable as possible. I assume this would involve some kind of clock multiplier/divider, PLL, etc. The range of frequencies I would like to be able to configure at runtime would be something like 200ksps up to about 20Msps (one clock cycle per sample). I don't need extremely tiny frequency steps in this range.

The ideal answer would reference specific part numbers with detailed reference designs. I can deal with single ended or differential clocks. Configuration of the clock generation would most conveniently be with 3.3v CMOS logic, though level translation is certainly a viable option there.

Comment: Requesting specific products is off-topic for StackExchange. However, I think your question, for the most part, fits.

Comment: No specific PN's, but check out SiLabs.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just sample at 20 Msps, and then decimate afterwards?

Comment: @The Photon - memory bottlenecks to some extent, processing capabilities to a greater extent, unnecessary added complexity of multirate signal processing algorithms (compared to no processing). Power could be a factor, but i think it's probably not in this case. It's an interesting thought that I will think about a bit more.

Comment: If you want 'cleaner' data certainty then it pays to over-sample by 4 to 16 times, then take the average of the samples. It really gets rid of jitter and spikes. If you can manage that in your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for are called "programmable clock generators", as your title says (do a google search for this). These are typically self-contained oscillators with a programming interface and, often, multiple voltage outputs, and single-ended and diffential outputs. 200KHz to 20MHz with 3.3V output should be easy to find. Other characteristics to check out include jitter and stability.

Comment: I agree with the "programmable clock generators". The less parts on the board, the cleaner the clock signals will be.

Comment: Ugh, seems I was closer to what I was looking for than I thought...